# ¿Cómo obtener los valores seleccionados de una dataTable sin importar la paginación?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo una tabla donde obtengo los datos de las columnas de las filas seleccionadas por medio de un checkbox.

El problema es que al ponerle paginación, cuando selecciono cualquier checkbox de cualquier pagina, al seleccinar un boton de aceptar solo obtiene los primeros checkbox de la pagina en donde me encuentro, ejemplo: si al seleccionar el boton de aceptar me encuentro en la pagina 2 solo toma esos checkbox seleccionados de la pagina 2, los demas checkbox seleccionados de otras paginas no los agrega al arreglo.
Este es un ejemplo de mi tabla:

```
<table class="table" id="tableImport">
        <thead>
            <tr>
           <th>Seleccion</th>
           <th>Numero</th>
           <th>Cliente</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   1
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente1
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   2
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente2
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   3
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente3
               </td>      
           </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Este es el script dataTable par la paginación, filtros y demas:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tableImport').DataTable();
} );
```

Por ultimo el script con el que obtengo los datos de las filas seleccionadas:

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
            $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){
              console.log($(this).text());
            });
            });
```

Comment: Según parece al paginar se eliminan los elementos anteriores del DOM, por eso no funciona como esperas.... En [esta página](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/52503/persist-checkbox-selection-in-pagination) hay un par de soluciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas crear una variable que contenga la tabla y luego buscas todos los inputs dentro de la misma.  Quedaria asi:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#tableImport').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 2
} );
$("#submit").click(function() {
table.$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
            $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){
              console.log($(this).text());
            });
            });
            })
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tableImport">
        <thead>
            <tr>
           <th>Seleccion</th>
           <th>Numero</th>
           <th>Cliente</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   1
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente1
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   2
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente2
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   3
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente3
               </td>      
           </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: Oye como puedo guardar solo el dato de la columna "Numero" en un array de las filas seleccionadas.

Comment: Puedes agregar una clase a la columna que quieres guardar